# AngularJS Error: Cannot find module './transports/xhr'

Tags: angularjs

I'm doing step 11 of [this tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11), and when I run the unit tests, I am getting the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './transports/xhr'
```

This error just started happening at this step.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in exactly the same situation, but I got the exact same error.

Have you tried removing your node_modules directory and reinstalling the dependencies through `npm install`? That resolved my issue.

In addition, you might want to review your logs - if `npm install` shows any errors they might help identify the problem (that's how I found that the transports directory wasn't being handled properly).